# Response.Redirect в веб-приложении ASP.NET вызывает падение процесса w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Допустим у меня есть простое веб-приложение на ASP.NET 4.0:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
}
```

По факту этот код выполняет следующее (подробнее почему так - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...в response записываются данные...
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
}
```

На моей машине (Windows 10 Pro + IIS) этот код приводит к завершению процесса пула IIS с кодом ошибки 0x0 (редирект не происходит). На других машинах (которые не Windows 10) этот код просто генерирует исключение ThreadAborted, но процесс продолжает работать (редирект происходит). Кто-нибудь с этим сталкивался?

В системных логах есть кое-что:

**log #1**

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/AS

Process ID: 6700

Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Message: Thread was being aborted.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

**log #2**

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3dad
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3b2a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000b3e28
Faulting process id: 0x1a2c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0e4b1b3ed01cb
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 23b5298d-3b36-49c7-a294-de9c864b703f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 2):

Это баг в ASP.NET. Воспроизводился на одной из девелоперских машин у меня в команде, я нашел полузакрытый issue [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1605438/disabling-ryujit-breaks-asp-net), запостил дампы и детальное описание, они пошевелились и сделали хотификс:

[3088956](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3088957) -  Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

[3088956](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3088956) - Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2

[3088955](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3088955) - Windows 8, Windows Server 2012

Под Win 10 никто шаги для воспроизведения не постил, скорее всего для нее баг не чинили. Создайте на connect Issue с описанием проблемы.

Или, если вы вручную отключали RyuJIT (в реестре, или в конфиге приложения, через `useLegacyJit`), поставьте [фикс для него](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086251) и включите его обратно.